# How do you disable all text tracks in an AVMutableComposition?

Tags: ios, avplayer

Let's say I have an AVMutableComposition with 4 tracks: 1 video, 1 audio, and 2 text tracks. I can switch between the two text tracks by toggling the enabled flag like so:

`[_player.currentItem.tracks[2] setEnabled:NO];
[_player.currentItem.tracks[3] setEnabled:YES];`

However if I attempt to turn off captions by setting enabled NO on both tracks, the most recent text track will get stuck on the screen. Is there a way to disable all text tracks?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this ?? facing the same problem